# How to paginate through array of returned MongoDB data

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, pagination

I have a MEAN app that stores material data in MongoDB, and uses AngularJS so the user can navigate through all the materials to find what they are looking for. I have a collection of all materials, with a field that has a value for each category (lets say category 1, 2 , 3, etc.).

Here is user experience I'm looking for:
User clicks on category, which triggers query to mongo, which returns results of entire category into view. User can now scroll through all materials in that category. When user clicks on specific material, query sent to mongo, and results returned into view for specific material with more info. The user can now paginate through all materials from that view.

Problem:
When the user gets to the specific material view, they can only paginate forward through the rest of the materials, not backward to previous materials. For example, when in all materials view, they click on 10th material. Instead of being able to paginate to 9 and 11, they can only paginate forward to 11.

I know it is because I am creating an entirely new array for the specific material view, so that the clicked specific material is index 0 of new array. I don't know how else to get that user experience I described. I'm beginning to think MongoDB is not the right database for this... Any thoughts about how to get the proper pagination?

Code:

All material view:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="center">
        <h3>All materials</h3>
      </div> 
      <br>
        <div class="col m3" dir-paginate="material in graniteStuff | itemsPerPage: pageSize">
          <a ui-sref="material({id: material.material_category_id, offset: $index})"><div class="card">
            <div class="card-image small">
                <img ng-src="http://stuff.com/uploads/materials/{{material.material_id}}/300X300/thumbnail/{{material.material_photo_name}}">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content" id="color">
              <h5>{{ material.material_name }}</h5>
              <p>{{ $index }}</p> 
            </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
```

Specific material view:

```
div class="row">      
        <div class="col m12" dir-paginate="material in scrollStuff | itemsPerPage: 1">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <h5 class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">{{ material.material_name }}<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></h5>
              </div>
              <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                <img class="activator" ng-src="http://stuff.com/uploads/materials/{{material.material_id}}/1280X720/{{material.material_photo_name}}">
              </div>
              <div class="card-reveal" id="reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4"><h3>{{ material.material_name }}</h3><i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p><strong>Description: </strong>{{ material.material_description }}</p>
                <p><strong>Other Names: </strong>{{ material.material_other_names }}</p>
                <p><strong>Country of Origin ID: </strong>{{ material.material_country_of_origin }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
      </div>    
    </div>
```

Controller for specific material view and pagination:

```
.controller('ScrollCtrl', function($scope, scrollFactory, $stateParams) {
    $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
    $scope.offset = $stateParams.offset;
    scrollFactory.getScrollStuff($scope.id)
    .then(function(scrolls) {
        // loop for pointer

        var newArray = [];
        var matArray = scrolls;
        var offset = parseInt($scope.offset, 10);
        if (offset > 91) {
            offset = parseInt($scope.offset - 1, 10);
        } else {
            offset = parseInt($scope.offset, 10);
        }
        // console.log(offset);
        for(var i = 0; i < matArray.length; i++) {
            var pointer = (i + offset) % matArray.length;
            newArray.push(matArray[pointer]);
        }

        $scope.scrollStuff = newArray;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }); 
})
```

Query to MongoDB:

```
app.get('/material/:id', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('moreInfoPhotos').find({"material_category_id": req.params.id}).toArray(function(err, results) {
        res.json(results);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Form UI side you have to send the **min** and **max** variable .

for example on first page values for min and max will be :
`min = 0 and max = min+20` (suppose you are showing 20 records per page)

second page will max and min value will be :

```
min = 20 and max = min+20 ;
```

Mongo query will add two new constraint i.e skip and limit :

```
db.collection('moreInfoPhotos').find({"material_category_id": req.params.id}).skip(min).limit(max);
```

Comment: Where do I set min/max values on frontend?

Comment: That you have to calculate every time you go from page 1 to page 2 or page 2 to page3 . As i mentioned in my answer for 1st page you have to send min = 0 and max = 20